# Linking CSS and JS files for accordion list - not functioning as separate files

Tags: css, javascript, html

I am learning how to make an accordion list and have found the following code (HTML, CSS, and JS) from www.w3schools.com. If I run the code locally, as one .html file, it works as intended. However, if I separate it into three files, and link the CSS and JS files in my HTML file, the drop down list does not work. I am (very) new to web development and would appreciate any explanation I can get for this! Thanks in advance.

Original Code (all in one document):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the     user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus"     sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>TEXT 1</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>TEXT 2</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>TEXT 3</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }   
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the HTML file linking the CSS and JS as separate files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mystyling.css">
    <title>Page TItle</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="./myjavascript.js"></script>

<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>

<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When     the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus"     sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
      <p>TEXT 1</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>TEXT 2</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>TEXT 3</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS and CSS files are just the JS and CSS files copy-and-pasted to other files (saves as .js, and .css, respectively).

Comment: Have you checked for errors in developer tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick note, you want to link your  at the bottom of the body. You'll want your HTML to load before the JavaScript does:

```
<script src="./myjavascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Second note, [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is more informative and reliable than W3 Schools. You'll want to train yourself to visit MDN over W3.

Where are your js and css files located? Can we see the code for those as well?

To debug more efficiently, open the html file in the browser and use the developer tools to let us know the errors you are getting (if there are any). option+command+j for mac and control+shift+j on windows, or just right-click inspect element.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much. And thanks for the MDN tip - I will check it out.

Could you please explain why the JS should be loaded at the bottom of the page versus at the top (where I have seen JS most commonly)?

Comment: When you load the HTML document, you'll want all the elements and styling loaded before any JavaScript can be implemented. JavaScript adds functionality to the web page, and you don't want to add functionality before content. It could cause some weird bugs on the web page if JavaScript is loaded and begins manipulating the DOM before all of its content is loaded. Content first, then functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the directories here as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./mystyling.css">`. This is causing errors in selected directories I guess.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyling.css">
```

If the css file in folder use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="folder/mystyling.css">`

And for the js file, it is better to put the file at the end of body tag

```
<script src="myjavascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

If the code is small then try to write on the same file inside the script tag

```
<script> 
//Your code
</script>
```